# MS excel 2016 - How can I sort multiple columns preserving blank cells?

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have 3 different lists I want to line them up and see matches across rows, and blanks where there aren't rows.  These are usually alphanumeric words (IE membership groups).  In the attached image, the left is the raw data, and the right is what I want to see.  I have manually sorted/cut/pasted to show matches and misses.  Is there a way to do this with a few keystrokes?
 [image]

Comment: Is your data actually just alphabet? Are you sure this scales to the actual problem (unique values, no repeaters, etc)

Comment: Is a VBA solution acceptable?

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick for your data as it currently stands. If your actual data is not alpha characters this will not work

Insert this in `E2` and drag over & down as needed (till Z)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,CHAR(95+ROW(A2))),CHAR(95+ROW(A2)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: I think I made my example too simple.  I'm actually sorting security groups, like AD groups, and database profiles.  Obviously, I couldn't put those in my example, so I simplified it.  How could I modify this to sort full words?

Comment: I added a better screenshot of what I have to work with.